# Can Robot eat cursed weapons?

Tags: nuclear-throne

Robot's special ability consumes weapons for ammo or health, but cursed weapons cannot be dropped.

Can Robot eat cursed weapons?

[image: Picture of Robot next to a cursed weapon]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Robot can eat cursed weapons - however, rather than being granted health or ammo, you will instead take 7 damage.